# How can I set the source ip as the client ip in haproxy tcp mode

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy to proxy tcp flows to my tomcat backend. I would like to receive flows with the source ip address as the client ip (and not 127.0.0.1 as it is now). I've set the send-proxy option (I'm using haproxy 1.7.7) but it doesnt seem to make a difference. what am I doing wrong?

This is my haproxy config:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local4

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#------------------------------------------------------------------    
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend https
    mode tcp
    option tcp-smart-accept
    bind :::443 v4v6

    acl from_sa src 10.203.239.135
    use_backend tomcat-cp-events if from_sa
    default_backend apache

backend apache
    mode tcp
    option tcp-smart-connect
    server apache :50443 send-proxy

backend tomcat-cp-events
    mode tcp
    option tcp-smart-connect
    server tomcat :54600 send-proxy
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is so , please apply your answer. Your question is the first result in googling "haproxy forward client ip". It is sad you've not received enough attention.